# How to get DJI MSDK (v5) RTK location and fused Alti?

Tags: kotlin, dji-sdk

I want to get RTK info in Kotlin. I have a Fragment, where i define:

```
val RTKInf = RTKLocation()                            // RTK and fused
val RTKSts = RTKSystemState()                         // see if connected
```

Now, in OncreateView, I do:

```
var altFus   : Double? = 0.00
RTKCenter.getInstance().addRTKLocationInfoListener {

            if(it != null && it.rtkLocation != null) altFus = it.rtkLocation.getMobileStationLocation().getAltitude()

        }
```

But the value of Altfus is always zero.

I can netiehr find a documented or an undocumented `flightControllerKey` that might correspond to RTK.

Please help.